# Android start flash in zxing library

Tags: android, zxing, flashlight

i made an android app using zxing library for barcode scan. barcode reader start when i tap on button, this is the code:

```
//scan
    mScanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan);
    mScanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.setPackage("com.app.myapp");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    });
```

This code works fine and barcode scanner start. But i want to start also ledflashlight (if present) when barcode reader start. There is a way to start flashlight when zxing library start?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't force the flashlight on when you start the app. The idea is that the user is in the best position to control whether it's on or not. I wouldn't want an app turning on a bright light in the wrong situation.

Comment: I mean "when you start Barcode Scanner from your app, to start scanning"

Comment: Without flash, you cannot read barcode because too dark. You wouldn't a working app?

Comment: If it's dark, the light should be on to read the barcode. If it's not dark, it should not be on. You don't know whether it's too dark; the user does. So the app lets the user turn on the light, not the calling app. Don't understand your closing question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Camera camera  =Camera.open();
 Camera.Parameters p;
 p = camera.getParameters();
 p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
 camera.setParameters(p);

 CameraConfigurationUtils.setTorch(p,true);
```

Using this you can on the torch on android studio integrated dependicy library.

Comment: Thanks. `import android.hardware.Camera`, and it's deprecated.